# How to use a gamepad as a mouse in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I wish to use my gamepad to navigate in my qt gui, I already have a code to process my gamepad inputs but I don't know how to 'simulate' a mouse with the output of the joystick of my gamepad.
I saw this in a forum post but I don't know if it's what I'm looking for :

```
qApp->sendEvent(viewport(), &eve);
```

Is this going to draw and move a cursor as the mouse does ?
Thank you

Comment: You could use a `QLabel` with image as mouse cursor. Give it a pixmap. Provide `nullptr` as parent (to ensure that it becomes a window on its own). Make it sticking to top level (windows flags) to ensure that no over window is stacked over it. That's probably not a perfect mouse pointer but can be implemented with less effort.

Comment: Thanks, by the way I am on ubuntu, maybe there is a simplier way in cpp to simulate the mouse systeme wide, if none I will surely try your idea thanks !